# Is Android App StartUp Library effective?

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack, app-startup

Is using Google AppStartUp Library is a good aproach? Is it really effective and is it ok to add the initialization code of other 3rd party libraries at our content provider i.e workmanager , Firebace etc

According to me moving workmanager content provider code at our provider does not seem feasible. Can Some one help?

Answer (score 0):

The App Startup library provides a straightforward, performant way to initialize components at application startup.

You can provide inject to your Initializer class.